# Extension content script only opening about:blank

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have the following code in my chrome extension content script:

```
window.open(chrome.extension.getURL("options.html"),'_blank');
```

But whenever I try this, I just get a new tab with about:blank, not one with my options page.

When I run the same code (through the developer tools console) on the options page, it works properly. If I launch an alert with the text `chrome.extension.getURL("options.html")`, it works as expected.

[This chrome documentation page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) suggests that what I'm doing should work correctly. So, how should I go about trying to fix this?

EDIT:

I believe this has something to do with the content security policy.

- If I inject a link to the page and just click on it, I get about:blank
- If I inject a link and I right-click, and then either open in new tab/window or copy URL, it works fine.
- If I inject a redirect, I get redirected to about:blank
- If I inject the text of the URL anywhere, it works fine.
- If I inject the exact URL (no chrome.extension.getURL, etc.), from ANY non-extension page, it doesn't work.

So I guess my new (more general) question is, **how can I launch my options page from a content script?**

Comment: Use `chrome.tabs.create()` to open the window.  Use `sendMessage` to trigger it, if need be.

Comment: @BrockAdams I don't have a background page running, and I want to try to avoid taking up 20KB of memory in the browser forever if it's only used the first time the user loads a certain page after the extension is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to use your HTML-file (or any other resource) outside of the context of your extension (e.g. in a web-page), you need to add the target HTML file in the **[`web_accessible_resources`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html)** section of your manifest. E.g.:

**Extension file-structure:**

```
          root-dir/
           |_____manifest.json
           |_____content.js
           |_____options.html
```

**content.js:**

```
/* Append a link to the web-page's body */
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = chrome.extension.getURL("options.html");
a.target = "_blank";
a.textContent = "My HTML file";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": true,

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }],

    "web_accessible_resources": ["options.html"]
}
```